# insert Image in database

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I am new to asp.net and databases! I am trying to save image into database from the file upload control. i have tried it but it isn't working that is upon clicking the submit button, the data does not get added into the database neither showing any error! this is the code which I have tried

```
protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile && Page.IsValid)                //fileUpload and submit
    {
        string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

        if (fileExtension.ToLower() != ".jpg")
        {
            Labelupload.Text = "Only Files with .jpg extension are allowed";
            Labelupload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
            Labelupload.Text = "File Uploaded";
            Labelupload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;

            LabelSubmit.Text = "Submitted Succesfully";
            LabelSubmit.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Labelupload.Text = "Please select a file";
        Labelupload.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        LabelSubmit.Text = "Failed to Submit";
        LabelSubmit.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }

    // insert into database
    Work obj = new Work();

    /* Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);*/

    obj.listItem_1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    obj.listItem_2 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    obj.Description = TextBoxdescription.Text;
    obj.Date = TextBoxdate.Text;
    //obj.UploadedImage = bytes;

    int k = obj.insertmethod();

    TextBoxdescription.Text = "";   
}
```

Here is the `Work` class that contains the `insertmethod()` logic:

```
public class Work
{
    Clssqlconnection obj = new Clssqlconnection();

    public string listItem_1 { get; set; }
    public string listItem_2 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    //public Byte[] UploadedImage { get; set; }

    public int insertmethod()
    {
        obj.str = @"insert into [assign_Work] (listItem_1, listItem_2, Description, Date, UploadedImage)" +
             "values('" + listItem_1 + "','" + listItem_2 + "','" + Description + "','" + Date + "','" + UploadedImage + "')";
        return obj.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `obj.insertmethod()`.

Comment: you have missed the main code. show us what does `obj.insertmethod`?

Comment: insert method in class Work! Edited!!

Comment: So you have commented out the `Byte[]` that actually holds the image data and you expected it to work? Your code will not even compile.

Comment: I commented it when it wasn't working to check if i am making some mistakes with inserting images because previously without image the data did get inserted into the database

Comment: I'm not sure what your purpose is, but since you said you were new to databases, I'll offer this.  Instead of inserting images into the database, it might be better to just insert a varchar with the PATH/URL to the image.  That way, you are not taking up DB space, and the data will be easier to work with.  JM2C.  What if someone tries to insert 1GB images using this tool, or corrupt files?

Comment: Actually I want to Show the data on gridView along with the uploaded image!

Comment: and as far as the size of the file is concerned, I can limit the user to not upload the files if the file size exceeds, say 2MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to go into the database via a parameter.  You cannot have it in a raw SQL statement.  Try this:

```
public int insertmethod()
{

    obj.str = @"insert into [assign_Work] (listItem_1, listItem_2, Description, Date, UploadedImage)" +
         "values('" + listItem_1 + "','" + listItem_2 + "','" + Description + "','" + Date + "', ?)";
    obj.Parameters.AddWithValue("File", UploadedImage);

    return obj.ExecuteNonQuery();


}
```

Also, btw, you might want to consider using parameters for all of these values to avoid injection attacks.  For instance, what if your Description field had an apostrophe in it?

Comment: Okay let me try this!